# Injectivity of the $\mathbb{Z}$ -module $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, injective-module

Let $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$, for a given prime number $p$, be the $\mathbb{Z}$-module with generators $\{a_{i}\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and relations $pa_1=0$ and $pa_{i+1}=a_i$.

I would like to show that this module is injective. I know that it is enough to show that it is divisible, i.e. that for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ and any nonzero $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exists $y\in\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ such that $ry=x$.

Maybe I do not see something obvious, but have some trouble with showing divisibility in this case. Any hint?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Given $g\in \mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ and $n\gt 0$, when can you (and when can't you, and why) show that there exists $h$ with $nh=g$?

Comment: For $n$ being power of $p$ it is obvious. I do not see why it is true for others.

Comment: Are you clear that every element has order a power of $p$? If $\gcd(q,p)=1$, and $g$ has order $p^a$, then $\gcd(p^a,q)=1$, so you can find $x,y$ integers with $1=xp^a+yq$. Then $g = (xp^a + yq)g = x(p^ag)+q(yg) = q(yg)$.

Comment: I wasn't looking at orders. Thanks!